# WPF - content of derived window not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a custom control from which i want my Window classes to derive their functionality.

```
public class BaseWindow : Window
{
   protected int x;
   public BaseWindow(int x) {this.x = x;}
   public void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
          //code
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

now the deriving class .cs

```
public class SubWindow : BaseWindow
{
   public SubWindow(int x):base(x)
   {
          InitializeComponent();
   }
 }
```

and the xaml of SubWindow

```
<src:BaseWindow x:Class="Client.SubWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Client"  
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Singleplayer" Height="350" Width="550"
    MinHeight="350" MinWidth="550"
    KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
    >
<Grid  Margin="58,-160,-58,160">
    <StackPanel>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">

                <Image  Width="60" Height="60"/>
                <Label FontSize="40" Margin="0,0,0,0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" TextBlock.Foreground="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="Title">
                    <Label.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform AngleX="-4.826"/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Label.RenderTransform>
                </Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Background="White" Opacity=".9" Margin="5,0,5,0" Content="text1"/>
            <Button Background="White" Opacity=".9" Margin="5,0,5,0" Content="text2"/>
            <Button Background="White" Opacity=".9" Margin="5,0,5,0" Content="text3?"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" Margin="124,182,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56"/>
    </StackPanel>

 </Grid>
</src:GameWindow>
```

now when opening the SubWindow,it is empty.no stackpane or anything only a 
black background.if i use the same xaml and code without the inheritance
the window is showing it all.

so what am im missing here?
(i removed alot of the original code to make this readable,i hope my problem still exits within the code i left)

Thanks!